# code works on Windows but cannot get it to work on MAC (error 68)

Tags: macos, excel, vba

with the most kind help of an expert, I was able to achieve my target of 
1) automatically creating a folder structure based on entry in Column 3; and
2) automatically creating a hyperlink in the appropriate column

The code can be found below

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
If Not Intersect(Target, Columns(3)) Is Nothing Then
    Dim tr As String
    With Target
        tr = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & .Offset(, -2).Value
        If Len(Dir(tr)) = 0 Then
            MkDir tr
            MkDir tr & "\Subfolder 1"
            MkDir tr & "\Subfolder 2"
            MkDir tr & "\Subfolder 3" & "\Sub-subfolder 1"
            .Hyperlinks.Add .Offset(, 4), tr, TextToDisplay:="Name"
        End If
    End With
End If

End Sub
```

I have been trying to get this to work on Mac but I always get and error 68 and then debugger opens on line

```
If Len(Dir(tr)) = 0 Then
```

I have tried changing the `\` within inverted commas in the line below

```
tr = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & .Offset(, -2).Value
```

to

- using `:`
- using `\`
- using `" "` (basically empty space)
- I tried changing `"(denominator)"` to `application.pathseparator` - still nothing.

Absolutely nothing.

The user has kindly suggested this webpage http://www.rondebruin.nl/mac.htm#Directory 
(see section Make a director when it does not exist) which might indeed work - the problem I see with that is that it does not seem to check if a folder already exists and also I am not quite clear on how I would create the sub-folders.

But for some (stubborn/silly?) reason, I am convinced that this must work somehow and I am over-complicating life.

Any thoughts?

Luke

Comment: Change backslashes \ to slashes /.

Comment: Hi Alfrabravo, already tried that - guess it is not clear when I said this in the question. Have tried changing backslashes to forward slashes, colons, even spaces. Nothing

Comment: What is the value of `ThisWorkbook.Path` on that line? Does can you check if `tr` exists before you find the length of `Dir(tr)`?

Comment: `Debug.print tr` - is it what you expect? And you should definitely use `Application.Pathseparator` in place of "\" if you need to be cross-platform.

Comment: Brad, a strange thing. Path seems to be /users/username/desktop. However, when I was debugging the code, the path appears as "Macintosh HD:users:username:Desktop" the path is valid and that is indeed where I am trying to create a folder with the name equal to the Value in Cell A. But for some reason, it does not create the folder!

Comment: Funny thing - I got this to work by doing the following 1) changed \ to : 2)removed the line If Len(Dir(tr)) = 0 Once I did this, the folders with name as value on Cell A are now created! 2) then got a series of error 76 messages - looks like it had to do with the length of the path for subfolders/ solved that too 3) also had to change the line .Hyperlinks.Add .Offset(, 4), tr, TextToDisplay:="Name" to .Hyperlinks.Add .Offset(, 4), tr

Comment: So in a nutshell, I have found a work-around. But any ideas from anyone as to why this worked? Tbh, the If Len(Dir(tr)) = 0 is quite useful so would be VERY happy to have this as a feature. Point 3 is less critical but also very Nice to Have.

Comment: Tim, maybe. could you elaborate on how and what?

Comment: Good morning all, any ideas? I am really snookered by this :-(

Comment: @User - I thought you had it working?  As for my earlier comment, I was just suggesting you add `Debug.Print tr` to make sure `tr` really contained what you thought it did.  The link to Ron's page has all the info you need to get this up and running on a Mac.

Comment: Hi Tim, I was a bit hesitant to set this up based on the webpage as it more or less meant re-editing the whole code and (devil being in the details) something going wrong and spending hours to fix it. I am really perplexed as to why it is working like this tbh with you, with this work-around. sometimes it is good to know why something works as well as why it does not :-)

Comment: The other thing is that I am not sure this is cross platform, which would be ideal as well.

Answer (score 1):

On Mac, you should use forward slash, /.

Since you do not really know whether you're on a PC or a Mac, I suggest to use the filesystem object instead of shell calls you referred to because doing that you would also need to know whether you're calling a windows command line or mac bash script. They're not the same. : )

Here it is described: http://www.tek-tips.com/faqs.cfm?fid=4116

Comment: Laszlo, thanks for the link? Should I assume that this link refers to code that works both in Mac as well as Windows? I thought I read somewhere that FSO does not work on Mac?

Comment: Well I'd assume that. I never used Microsoft stuff on my Mac so I'm not 100% sure, sorry.